# Displayed row details always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="level4.Workers"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:level4"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Workers" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--The workers DataBase-->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="WorkersDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:WorkerAdapter}"/>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Workers" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource WorkersDataProvider}" MethodName="getWorkers"/>

        <!--The person data provider-->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PersonDataProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type local:PersonAdapter}" />
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Person" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource PersonDataProvider}" MethodName="getPersonByID">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Workers}}">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="WorkersSelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="workers ID" Binding="{Binding WID}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="salary (k/m)" Binding="{Binding SALARY}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="worker's rank" Binding="{Binding WRANK}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Seniority" Binding="{Binding SENIORITY}" />
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="works in branch:" Binding="{Binding BRANCHNUM}"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Person}}">
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Person}}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The function `WorkersSelectionChanged` is the following:

```
 private void WorkersSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
            ObjectDataProvider PersonProvider = this.FindResource("Person") as ObjectDataProvider;
            System.Data.DataRowView drv = grid.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
            PersonProvider.MethodParameters[0] = Int32.Parse(drv["PID"].ToString());

        }
```

The function `getPersonByID` is the following:

```
public DataView getPersonByID(Int32 PID)
        {
            DataRow datarow = dt.Select(String.Format("PID = {0}", PID)).FirstOrDefault();
            DataTable ret = new DataTable();
            ret.ImportRow(datarow);
            return ret.DefaultView;
        }
```

(dt is of type DataTable)

The problem: the table of workers displays correctly, but the row details is always an empty table. I checked with the debugger, and every time I select a row the function `getPersonByID` is called, with the correct value for PID, the DataTable `ret` has some rows, but the table displayed is still empty.

Where did I go wrong?

I'm using VS2012, .NET framework 4.5

Comment: did you try to return `return new DataView(ret)`?

Comment: @dkozl Just did. Nothing changed.

Comment: I may be that your new table does not have columns defined

Comment: @dkozl I think you found it - looking with the debugger, I really don't have columns. How can I get the columns defined?

Comment: Assuming that `dt` is also `DataTable` instead of creating your `DataTable` do `DataTable ret = dt.Clone();`

Comment: @dkozl thanks - this worked. If you can put it into an answer, I will mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up comments your new `DataTable` has no columns so instead of creating new `DataTable` use [`DataTable.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx)

> Clones the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas and constraints.

so in your case replace

```
DataTable ret = new DataTable();
```

with

```
DataTable ret = dt.Clone();
```